# angularjs - nginclude - asp.net mvc - loading all scripts again

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I have been using ng-include in my asp.net mvc application and have had no issues with the same.
I happened to check the source code and found that nginclude is also loading all the scripts (in master page) again.
Please check the attached snapshot of the source code. 
Is that an expected behavior? Am I doing anything wrong about it?
This is how I normally use the include:

```
<div ng-include="'/Home/PDFReport/'"></div>
```

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: It will load everything again if you loading the entire View, that has the Layout view as parent. You must load this as PartialView, that will skip the parent Laytout and then this scripts.

Comment: Hi Wes, the PDFReport page is a partial page only. It has no layout/master page to it.

Comment: Bummer! Sorry I found the mistake Wes Foster. I was returning the page as view from the controller which has to be PartialView. Thank you very much.

Comment: How do i put the comment from Wes Foster as answered. Sorry I am new to this site.

Comment: Just Answered below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return at your controller the View `PDFReport` as `PartialView`, then It will avoid to load the entire Layout and whole bunch of scripts.

At your Controller:

```
public ActionResult PDFReport()
{
  /*Other stuff comes here*/
  return PatialView();
}
```